# Angle range when scalar product of vectors less or equal to zero

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, angle

Given two vectors $a$ and $b$, what is the possible angle between them when $ab \leq 0$?

Comment: I assume you are using an inner product here.  This is more often written as $a\cdot b$ or as $\langle a, b\rangle$.  Now... you should have learned something relating the inner product of two vectors to their magnitudes and angle between them.  Do you [recall what that is?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Geometric_definition)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ be two nonzero vectors. I'm going to denote their dot product by $\langle \vec{a},\vec{b} \rangle$. Now, we note that:

$$\langle \vec{a},\vec{b} \rangle = \|a\| \cdot \|b\| \cdot \cos(\theta)$$

where $\theta$ is the angle between them so that $\theta \in [0,\pi]$. Now, $\|a\| > 0$ and $\|b\| > 0$. So, all we need to do is to observe that:

$$\cos(\theta) \leq 0$$

and this is true when $\theta \in \left[\frac{\pi}{2},\pi \right]$.  I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Typesetting note, it is preferred to use `\|a\|` yielding $\|a\|$ over using `||a||` which instead yielded $||a||$

Comment: Is that better? I was looking for something like \norm{} but that doesn't seem to exist lol. Thanks :)